# Creating pandas dataframes from nested json file that has lista

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

[a picture on how the data look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAkt8.png)

So, I have a json file with data, the file is really nested, I want to take only the words and create a new dataframe for each post id. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'member_info.vocabulary':[[], [{'post_iD':'3913', 'word':'Twisters'},
                                                  {'post_iD':'3911', 'word':'articulate'}]]})

df['words'] = df['member_info.vocabulary'].apply(lambda x: [y.get('word') for y in x])
print (df)

                              member_info.vocabulary                   words
0                                                 []                      []
1  [{'post_iD': '3913', 'word': 'Twisters'}, {'po...  [Twisters, articulate]
```

And if get one element lists only add `str[0]` for select first value of lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'member_info.vocabulary':[[], [{'post_iD':'3913', 'word':'Twisters'}]]})

df['words'] = df['member_info.vocabulary'].apply(lambda x: [y.get('word') for y in x]).str[0]
print (df)

                      member_info.vocabulary     words
0                                         []       NaN
1  [{'post_iD': '3913', 'word': 'Twisters'}]  Twisters
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply :). Very helpful.